# Creating a class and Going into the Frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to create this Panel into a class but it is not working, trying to make it go into the Frame as well. I am getting the "It is not a class error"

Please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Programming is fun until you are stuck for hours on one problem.
Panel:

```
import java.awt.Button;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    public TopPanel{
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Create a frame");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        Button button = new Button("111");
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(Crse);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CourseGUI extends JFrame {
    public CourseGUI()
    {

        super("CourseGUI Frame");


        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);

        topPanel.setPreferredSize(d);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(800,600);


        TopPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TopPanel.add(Crse, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CourseGUI();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advanced.

I changed the TopPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    public TopPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(Crse);
        panel.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about including the actual error message (so we know where it is coming from) ?

Comment: I got 39 error messages of TopPanel not exisiting, my teaching told us not to make TopPanel a main method. It has to be a class, once I got rid of the main and changed the public static void main to public TopPanel, errors went everywhere, help thanks

Answer (score 1):

`TopPanel` is your class name, `topPanel` is your `JPanel` instance. (Java is case sensitive).

Lines like

```
TopPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
TopPanel.add(Crse, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Are trying to use the class which is not what you intended...

Your are also missing `()` on the line `public TopPanel {` (the one inside the class, not the one defining the class)

`Crse` is a local variable in the `TopPanel` creator, so you can't use it inside `CourseGUI()`

`TopPanel` is creating a frame to put itself into which is weird...

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but nothing is showing up, the "Course Info" I wanted to show up isn't showing up at all. As a matter of fact, it is a completely blank gui, why is that? Sorry I'm very very new to this

Comment: In the code above, the `CourseGUI` class just creates a normal `JPanel`, not a `TopPanel` (which contains your GUI). Note: You'll need to remove the Frame stuff from the `TopPanel` class too.

Comment: How do I get the TopPanel to be used?

Comment: `JPanel panel = new TopPanel();` You really need to talk to your tutor. this is basic stuff!

Comment: My teacher said something about TopPanel tp;
tp=newTop();
this.add(tp.BorderLayout.North);